# Unable to find locator from google-chart tool-tip - Protractor & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am new to protractor and type script. I am unable to find element locator from google-chart tooltip.

I have google chart which is showing data according to date. If I hover mouse on today date, it's showing tooltip with below data:

```
 123
 231
 10
```

I have to find locator for 123, 231, and 10.

```
<summary-report>
 <div>
   <google-chart>
       <div>
       <div aria-label="test sample"..........>
          <table>
             <tbody>
                <tr><tr>
                <tr><tr>
                <tr><tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>123</td>
                   <td>231</td>
                   <td>10</td>
                <tr>
```

I have tried below xpath, but not working.

```
static test1 = Target.the("test1).located(by.xpath("//summary-report//div[contains(@aria-label, 'test sample')]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]");
```

Comment: First you have to implement mouseover method on element, wait for the tooltip, and then check the value.

What do you have so far?

Comment: 'browser.actions().mouseMove(test1).perform();', but I can't pass target type locator here. MouseMove method expects web element.

Comment: here you have an example with mouse hover: https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/issues/87

Comment: tried below code, but getting " " value from google chart tooltip. Is below code correct? I have also written hover code in my task.ts file. **actor.attemptTo(Hover.over(LocatorClass.graphValue), Wait.for(Duration.ofMillis(5000)),                                                 
Wait.until( LocatorClass.test1, Is.visible()), );                                                                                             return actor.toSee(Text.of(locatorClass.test1)).then((test1text) => {
    return expect(actor.toSee(Text.of(locatorClass.test2))).to.eventually.equal(test1text);**
});

Comment: As mentioned in problem description, we have div tag inside google-chart, which is giving us data for 11 days. I have to pick 4th. I tried below Xpath, but it's returning " " value.                                                      **xpath("/html/body/app-root/test1/div/div/test2/div/div[2]/div[1]/google-chart/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")); **